# Wix Toolset prerequisites: Check for .Net Framework

Tags: wix

I have a wix bundle project that I am editing (ver 3.10). I am trying to use the wixnetfxextensions to install .net framework 4.6 if it is not already installed. I created an exepackage that uses the  WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED property. I'm guessing I am not using this correctly. Any help on how to use that? Currently the .net framework will not install not matter what.

```
  <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="redist_vc140" />
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx461Full" />
      <MsiPackage Id="MSI_Installer" SourceFile="C:\Installer.msi"/>
  </Chain>

  <Fragment>
      <PropertyRef Id="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"/>
      <!-- Install .NET 4.6.1 -->
      <PackageGroup Id="NetFx461Full">
          <ExePackage Id="NetFx461"
           DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1"
           Compressed="no"
           Cache="yes"
           PerMachine="yes"
           Permanent="yes"
           Protocol="netfx4"
           Vital="yes"
           SourceFile="..\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
           UninstallCommand="/q /norestart"
           RepairCommand="/q /norestart"
           DetectCondition="NOT WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" />
       </PackageGroup>  
  </Fragment>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing a lot of extra work to install .net that you don't actually need to do.

To add .net 461 to your installer just include the netfxextension and add

```
<Bundle>
    <PayloadGroup Id="NetFx461RedistPayload">
        <Payload Name="redist\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
             SourceFile="C:\path\to\redists\in\repo\NDP461-KB3102436-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"/>
    <PayloadGroup/>
</Bundle>
```

so that the full installer is included in your bootstrapper. You can ignore this and then the bootstrapper will download the installer but if the customer doesn't have an internet connection they won't be able to install .net.

Then in your chain just add

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx461Redist"/>
```

I used [this](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/install_dotnet.html) as a reference and checked the [wix source](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/ext/NetFxExtension/wixlib/NetFx461.wxs) to see what the 
 name of .net 461 being used is in netfxextension.

---

Sean Hall mentioned that bundles don't even use properties so what I had written here doesn't apply at all in this situation. (And it was also incorrect)

Comment: The `WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_46_OR_LATER_INSTALLED` property isn't working because properties are for MSI's not bundles.

Comment: Yep that would also do it. The wix netfxextension uses <WixVariable Id="NetFx461WebDetectCondition" Value="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx461MinRelease)" Overridable="yes" /> as it's default detect condition for the net461 exepackage.

Comment: The document of [PackageGroups](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html)

Answer (score 0):

Did what Brian Sutherland suggested: Added the WxsVariable that compares the .netframework with the determined minimum release number. then make that a detectcondition in the exepackage